# How to keep track of word count in text file

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to count the occurrences of every word within a text file (case insensitive) and store the words and their counts in a list.

This is my object class for the every word to be stored in the list,

```
public class WordItem
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and my code function to parse the text files

```
public List<WordItem> FindWordCount()
{
    //I've successfully parsed the text file into a list
    //of words and stripped punctuation up to this point
    //and stored them in List<string> wordlist.

    List<string> wordlist;
    List<WordEntry> entries = new List<WordEntry>();

    foreach (string word in wordlist)
    {
        WordItem temp = new WordItem();
        temp.Word = word;
        temp.Count = 1;
        entries.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

How can I edit my word count function to prevent duplicates words in the list, and instead increment the count value everytime I find the word an additional time?

Comment: I'd recommend instead using a `Dictionary<string, int>` - you can easily see if the dictionary contains a particular word and increment it if so, otherwise add it.  Having said that, given that you already have a list of words in a `List<string>`, a bit of linq would probably give you what you want quite easily.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I agree a Dictionary would be easier, but I need to return in this instance a List specifically. EDIT: I'm not familiar with Linq could you elaborate or point me to somewhere I can read about it.

Comment: @user3277752 You could create a list from the dictionary by doing `var list = dictionary.Select(kvp => new WorItem { Word = kvp.Key, Count = kvp.Value}).ToList();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary` with a case insensitive string-comparer:

```
public IEnumerable<WordItem> FindWordCount(IEnumerable<string> wordlist)
{
    var wordCount = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    foreach (string word in wordlist)
    {
        int count = 0;
        bool contained = wordCount.TryGetValue(word, out count);
        count++;
        wordCount[word] = count;
    }
    foreach (var kv in wordCount)
        yield return new WordItem { Word = kv.Key, Count = kv.Value };
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
var wordList = new string[] { "A", "a", "b", "C", "a", "b" };
var wordCounts = FindWordCount(wordList).ToList();
```

Comment: You need an `else` with `count = 1;`.

Comment: shouldn't count initially be 1?

Comment: @LorentzVedeler The `TryGetValue` will reset `count` to zero if there is no entry in the dictionary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Even better than an `if` and `else`.

Comment: this is the answer is expected from Tim:

`var Result = wordlist.GroupBy(m => m).Select(x => new WordItem(){  Word = x.Key, Count = x.Count()});`

Comment: What is the purpose of `bool contained = `?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Could be useful when debugging.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: it has no purpase. It's just there to explain OP what `TryGetValue` does and if he wants to debug his code.

Comment: @juharr you're absolutely right, pretty obvious when you think about it :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right - ok.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something :)

Comment: @fubo: you can use LINQ but if i already have a method, i prefer the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are also pretty single-line solutions:

```
IEnumerable<WordItem> countedList = wordlist.Distinct().Select(word => new WordItem() { Word = word, Count = wordlist.Count(compWord => word.Equals(compWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) });
```

or, if you prefer a dictionary, in order to be able to search for specific words later:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = wordlist.Distinct().ToDictionary<string, string, int>(word => word, word => wordlist.Count(compWord => word.Equals(compWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Performance is of course a bit less than Tim Smelters solution, because of the Count()-Call (which leads to `O(n^2)`) but using `C# 6.0` you'd be able to write down the method with a lambda expression for definition instead of a body.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and with your types:

```
public string[] wordList;

public class WordItem
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<WordItem> FindWordCount()
{
  return from word in wordList
         group word by word.ToLowerInvariant() into g
         select new WordItem { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count()};
}
```

Comment: While `ToLowerInvariant` avoids issues like the turkish-i problem it simply ignores the  current culture which might not be desired. It also needs to create a new string for every word which is not efficient.